# input 3 times and generate 3 graphs function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matplotlib, graph

First of all Thanks for your help.
As I said at title, I want to make input 3 times and generate 3 graphs function

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = range(1, 1)

for i in times:
   
    def my_func2(x):
        a=int(input())
        return x**a

        x=np.linspace(0,2)
        y=my_func2(x)

        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.xlabel("x",size=14)
        plt.ylabel("y",size=14)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
    i=i+1
```

Comment: you only define function but you forgot to execute this function. But you could define function before `for`-loop and execute it inside `for`-loop`

Comment: you have wrong indentations - and this change everything in Python. You try to plot inside `my_func2()` and run `y=my_func2(x)` inside `def my_func2(x):`

Comment: if you want to repeate 3 times then use `range(3)` instead of `range(1,1)` and without `i = i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentations - and this change everything in Python. You try to plot inside `my_func2()` and you run `y=my_func2(x)` inside `def my_func2(x):` - so you never run this function.

And if you want to repeat 3 times then use `range(3)` instead of `range(1, 1)` and without `i = i + 1`

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- functions ---

def my_func2(x):
    a = int(input())  
    return x**a

# --- main ---

for i in range(3):
    x = np.linspace(0,2)
    y = my_func2(x)

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel("x", size=14)
    plt.ylabel("y", size=14)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

---

But I would do it without function

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --- main ---

for i in range(3):
    a = int(input())  

    x = np.linspace(0,2)
    y = x**a

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel("x", size=14)
    plt.ylabel("y", size=14)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```